# Using Async custom Validator in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular

[Stackblitz link  to see code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7nn5mg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

1. I want to use a custom Async validator in my code to check if certain pin-codes exist in my database or not and then take some action in the HTML reactive form
2. My HTML element instantly calls the method before the validator is done validating so the angular make the "pending" status true as the validation is pending

**What I want??**

- I want the html to call my method after all the validators are done evaluating
  -->do not suggest to use set timeout

*if you can help me with the proper way of doing this it will be great.*

**Currently** I am using `settimeout` function inside my method and it is working fine but it is not the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove this line from the template

```
(input)="userForm.get('pinCode').value != '' ? checkForPincode() : null"
```

this is responsible for checking calling `checkForPincode()` as soon as the user presses a key.

2. Forms, and fields, have various event streams attached to them, I think `statusChanges` will be the best. You can, after the form is created, do

```
this.userForm.get('pinCode').statusChanges
    .subscribe(() => this.checkForPincode());
```

statusChanges can be things like VALID, INVALID, PENDING.

To save yourself unnecessary checks, you can pass it through `distictUntilChanged` operator

```
this.userForm.get('pinCode').statusChanges
    .pipe(
        distictUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(() => this.checkForPincode());
```

or even do the check for field validity right there:

```
this.userForm.get('pinCode').statusChanges
    .pipe(
        distictUntilChanged(),
        filter(value => value === 'VALID'),
    ).subscribe(() => this.userForm.get('Province').enable());
```